# Prevent <textarea> from losing focus to keep mobile keypad

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a webapp which needs to be mobile compatible in regards to the chat feature.  Currently when you click on the area of the screen with the `<textarea>` some additional buttons pop up that were not there before (to save screen space).  These buttons are usable, but currently what happens is that when you click on them, the `<textarea>` realizes that it is no longer the focus and thus the mobile keyboard disappears.  This creates an overall jumpy experience.

Can anyone think of a JS solution that will fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, virtual keyboards are wildly variable and generally uncontrollable by the webpage.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I guess he's trying to keep virtual keyboard persistent by keeping focus on text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo-programming solution:

```
function buttonClick
    do stuff...
    restore focus to textarea
```

That's all actually.

---

So, a JS solution would be:

```
function buttonClickHandler(){
    // do button stuff...
    document.getElementById('myTextarea').focus();
}
```

Assuming that:

- `buttonClickHandler` is the button's onclick event function
- `myTextarea` is the id of the textarea

Comment: It's probably that in some mobile browsers, the textarea loses focus first, so the keyboard disappears, then the event happens, then the textarea regains focus, so the keyboard reappears. This would add another round of jumpiness...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, yup, I completely agree and was aware of that while writing the answer, though I think that's as close as you can get to keep the keypad on. Maybe (a big maybe) because the blur/focus happens within the same cycle, it might trick mobiles not to hide the keypad in the first place. Perhaps using `onmousedown`?

Comment: I have tested on Chrome for an Android device and this solution seems to work.  I think there is a timeout built into that browser for when it looses focus and when the keyboard goes away.  I will accept this answer once I get home and can test it on my device lab.

Comment: Be sure to test as widely as possible, but this does seem to be the closest you'll get if it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Yup, I think so, too, the same delay as between single click and double click, 300ms I believe. Not sure if that covers all OSes/devices, be careful. The next closest thing is building a custom textarea/keypad, which I'm not sure is worth it.

Comment: @Shomz I think(only suggestion) that we can focus on textarea, whenever any other visible elements are clicked. Will that work?

Comment: @SnazzySanoj, that's close to what I suggested - though I suggested only listening for those buttons, because I think forcing the keypad to stay on, even if, say, the user clicks outside of it purposely is a bad UX practice, right?

Comment: Yep, I agree with that..

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do this:

```
$('textarea')
    .focus() // set initial focus
    .on('blur', function () { // on blur
        $(this).focus(); // return focus
    });
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/v6do2utk/1/